# Responsive layout not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a website that works responsively in a desktop web browser with no problem ([www.coolnique.com](http://coolnique.com)) - however, when it's viewed on mobile it doesn't seem to pick up the correct screen size.

The meta tag I'm using is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
```

I'm viewing it on an iPhone and the viewport seems to think the device is double of what it actually is.

If you view it on desktop and play around with it and then check out the site on mobile you will see what I mean. I don't know what else could be affecting it!

If anyone wants any more details let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: No, I'm also using this JS: [http://coolnique.com/js/coolnique.js](http://coolnique.com/js/coolnique.js) with jquery 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember to validate your code first! When running your CSS through the validator, I got the error:

```
Parse Error 
/*layouts smaller than 600px, iPhone and mobiles*/ 
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), s...
```

It looks like you haven't closed your brace for the previous media query.

Comment: No problem, and don't worry, I've forgotten to do that on plenty of occasions! The site looks nice. :)